# Suppose $\alpha>0$ and $\{a_n\}\nearrow+\infty$ . Prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{a_{k+1}a_k^\alpha} $ converges.

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $\alpha>0$ and $\{a_n\}$ is an increasing sequence such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty$. Prove that
>   $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{a_{k+1}a_k^\alpha}
> $$
>   converges.

Since $\displaystyle\frac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{a_{k+1}^{\alpha+1}}\leq\int_{a_{k}}^{a_{k+1}}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha+1}}\,dx$, we can prove that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{a_{k+1}^{\alpha+1}}<\infty.
$$

I though by combining the definition of Riemann integration and the enlarging and reducing method may prove it. But I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: 
$${a_{k+1} - a_k \over a_{k+1}a_k^{\alpha}} = {1 \over a_k^{\alpha}} - {1 \over a_{k+1}a_k^{\alpha-1}}$$
If $\alpha \geq 1$ this is bounded by
$$
{1 \over a_k^{\alpha}} - {1 \over a_{k+1}^{\alpha}} $$

Answer (score 1):

I would break this into two cases. When $\alpha \geq 1$, you have
$$\frac{a_{k+1} - a_k}{a_{k+1} a_k^\alpha} = \frac{1}{a_k^\alpha} - \frac{1}{a_{k+1}a_k^{\alpha-1}} \leq \frac{1}{a_k^\alpha} - \frac{1}{a_{k+1}^\alpha}$$
so you can bound your sum by $1/a_1^\alpha$,
and when $\alpha < 1$, you can apply your integration idea slightly differently:
$$\frac{a_{k+1} - a_k}{a_{k+1} a_k^\alpha} = \frac{1/a_k - 1/a_{k+1}}{(1/a_k)^{1-\alpha}} \leq \int_{1/a_{k+1}}^{1/a_k} \frac{dx}{x^{1-\alpha}}$$
hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_{k+1} - a_k}{a_{k+1} a_k^\alpha} \leq \int_0^{1/a_1} \frac{dx}{x^{1-\alpha}} = \frac{1/\alpha}{a_1^\alpha}< \infty.$$